# Sorting a HashMap based on Value then Key?

Tags: java, sorting, hashtable, hashmap

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to sort a Map<Key, Value> on the values in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109383/how-to-sort-a-mapkey-value-on-the-values-in-java)

I have a HashMap of the type:

```
HashMap<String, Integer> h = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
```

The HashMap contains a list of Strings and the Integer is a counter for the number of times that String has been found. What I would like to be able to do is sort the HashMap based on the Integers, then on the alphabetical order of the Strings.

At the moment I am keeping a record of the largest occurrence of a word (variable named max) and displaying the values as follows:

```
public void print(){
    while(max > 0){
       for (String key : h.keySet()){
           if(h.get(key) == max){
               System.out.println(key + " " + h.get(key));
           }
       }
       max--;
    }
}
```

Which doesn't sort the values alphabetically, also it accesses the HashMap max*h(size) times.

What is the better solution?

Comment: @krock good find. Yep, exact same question.

Answer (score 16):

Here's a `Comparator` that sorts `Map.Entry` objects with `Comparable` keys and values:

```
public class ValueThenKeyComparator<K extends Comparable<? super K>,
                                    V extends Comparable<? super V>>
    implements Comparator<Map.Entry<K, V>> {

    public int compare(Map.Entry<K, V> a, Map.Entry<K, V> b) {
        int cmp1 = a.getValue().compareTo(b.getValue());
        if (cmp1 != 0) {
            return cmp1;
        } else {
            return a.getKey().compareTo(b.getKey());
        }
    }

}
```

You'd put all of the map entries into a list and then sort that:

```
List<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> list = new ArrayList<Map.Entry<String, Integer>>(h.entrySet());
Collections.sort(list, new ValueThenKeyComparator<String, Integer>());
```

Comment: Almost, I guess because because this way words with fewer occurrence come first..

Answer (score 4):

Look at [Google Guava libraries](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/). It has a [`Multiset`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn-history/r8/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multiset.html) which does the calculation for you and then you have [`Ordering`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn-history/r8/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Ordering.html) class that simplifies sorting.

All you need to do is to populate `Multiset` with your strings. It will maintain the frequency for you. Then you can sort on those strings using `Ordering`.

Answer (score 3):

Probably not the most elegant solution, but how about this?

```
//TreeSet with reversed natural ordering (big integers first)
Map<Integer, Set<String>> h = 
     new TreeMap<Integer, Set<String>>(Collections.reverseOrder());
//and use TreeSet for the set...
// ...    
// 
for(Map.Entry<Integer,Set<String>> entry : h.entrySet()){
    for(String str : entry.getValue()){
        System.out.println(str + " has occured " + entry.getKey() + " times.");
    }
}
```

Comment: `-1 * o1.compareTo(o2)` is flawed.  Consider the case where `compareTo` returns `Integer.MIN_VALUE`.

Comment: Actually I shouldn't have written my own code for reversing the natural order :P Substituting with the `Collections.reverseOrder()` method..

Answer (score -1):

you can use SortedMap interface to sort your HashMap. It's very easy - Automatic sorting. Refer to http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html. I didn't include any code here, but if you need, just add a comment. I'll give you a sample code.

Comment: -1, SortedMap sorts by key, rather than by value

Comment: A map that further guarantees that it will be in ascending key order, sorted according to the natural ordering of its keys (see the Comparable interface), or by a comparator provided at sorted map creation time