# How to sort out a TreeMap<String, Integer>?

Tags: java, treemap

I have a map: `TreeMap<String, Integer> m = new TreeMap<>();` where I have a whole alphabet and values, which shows how many times each letter was found in my text.

I want to sort that map in descending count order; that is, the most frequent letter is on the first line, and the last line of output indicates the least frequent letter. **If two letters have the same frequency, then the letter which comes first in the alphabet must appear first.** How to make it?

I tried with Comparator:

```
public int compare(String a, String b) {
        if (base.get(a) >= base.get(b) && a.compareToIgnoreCase(b) < 0) {
            return -1;
        } else {
            return 1;
        }
    }
```

but still, its not it, the output is:

```
D 3
E 3
A 2
S 5
```

Guys ... Found this before, this didnt help at all. Good output should be:

```
S 5
D 3
E 3
A 2
```

Comment: exact duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3074154/sorting-a-hashmap-based-on-value-then-key

Comment: another duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1448369/how-to-sort-a-treemap-based-on-its-values

Comment: @JohnJohnGa: no. My question is a little bit different. See my edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your comparator does not look right - this should work better:

```
public int compare(String a, String b) {
    if (base.get(a) > base.get(b)) {
        return -1;
    } else if (base.get(a) < base.get(b)) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        int stringCompare = a.compareToIgnoreCase(b);
        return stringCompare == 0 ? 1 : stringCompare; // returning 0 would merge keys
    }
}
```

Comment: @Katie Sorry it was in ascending order - amended.

Answer (score 3):

As the natural sort has nothing in common with your sorting wish:

```
List<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> entries = new ArrayList<>(m.entrieSet());

Collections.sort(entries, new Comparator<Map.Entry<String, Integer>>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Map.Entry<String, Integer >a, Map.Entry<String, Integer>b) {
        if (a.getValue() < b.getValue()) { // Descending values
            return 1;
        } else if (a.getValue() > b.getValue()) {
            return -1;
        }
        return -a.getKey().compareTo(b.getKey()); // Descending keys
    }    
});
```

Comment: +1.  It is an astoundingly bad idea to try to write a comparator by value like the OP is doing, and will doom your code to confusing, surprising, and impossible-to-debug messes.